Why does lseek() return ESPIPE, when driver doesn't provide implementation?
Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition states:

if the llseek method is missing from the device's operations, the
default implementation in the kernel performs seeks by modifying
filp->f_pos

Yet I have a character device for which driver doesn't implement lseek. Here are file op definitions for this device type:
https://github.com/Xilinx/dma_ip_drivers/blob/master/XDMA/linux-kernel/xdma/cdev_ctrl.c
But attempting lseek on this device returns ESPIPE:
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    uint32_t val=0x12345678;
    int fid=open("/dev/xdma0_user", O_RDWR);
    off_t lseek_ret=lseek(fid, 0x8ul, SEEK_SET);
    if (lseek_ret <0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Seek result: %d, errno: %s (%d)\n", lseek_ret, strerror(errno), errno );
    unsigned int c=write(fid, &val, sizeof(val));
    printf("written %u bytes\n", c);
    close(fid);
    return (0);
}

Output:
Seek result: -1, errno: Illegal seek (29)
written 4 bytes

I can't understand how this comes about. It can't stem from the driver: ESPIPE isn't even mentioned anywhere in it, so it must come from the kernel, which contradicts the quote above.
Has the default behaviour been altered?  Can it be somehow configured? How can be seen what kernel actually does (ideally source code)?
Kernel version is 5.10 (Debian 11).

The third edition of Linux Device Drivers was published in 2005, and llseek handling in the kernel has changed a few times since then. I won’t go into the history in detail, but if you’re curious you can start around “llseek: automatically add .llseek fop” and Jason Donenfeld’s llseek series, culminating in “fs: remove no_llseek” (merged in 5.19, so not relevant for the kernel version you’re interested in).
In 5.10, the default operation is no_llseek; see vfs_llseek:
    fn = no_llseek;
    if (file->f_mode & FMODE_LSEEK) {
        if (file->f_op->llseek)
            fn = file->f_op->llseek;
    }

Since the xdma driver doesn’t set .llseek, calls end up handled by no_llseek, which returns ESPIPE.

Thank you for solving this mystery, that also means that the driver may cause mischief since kernel 6.0, because kernel no longer checks for null pointer.
